# How to pull random N records from within a range of rows and keep iterating?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with `1-100` records I'm displaying in a feed.

When the page first loads I'd like to load a random unique `10` record iteration from say:

`80-90, 90-100, 1-10, 10-20 ....` all the way back to `80` and then stop so the all records get shown.

Next time the page loads I'd like it to start at another random 10:

`40-50, 50-60 ....` all the way back to 40.

Comment: can you add sample table result. with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` offered by MySQL.

First:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE LIMIT 10;
```

From the next run onward, do following:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Comment: this ill end at the end of the database thought I believe?

Comment: You can control on the script that you use. You can make OFFSET a variable and hit the database as required.

Comment: Yes, but say you start randomly at record 50. The offset in this case will keep going and then end at 100. but if I start randomly at 50 I'd like to go full circle and come back around.

Comment: You can control that by an additional condition - when you hit the limit, start over again.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to manage data how many time user has visited the page and from there you can load. With the help of row_number() take a serial number.

You can create temp table that if your has visited once then start from 80, if twice then from 40 etc..